# jquery insert new element into table cell without erasing other elements

Tags: jquery

A table contains several rows, each with four cells.

In a cell with `id=tdJane`, I already have two input elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tdBob">
            <input type="hidden" id="hida" value="some stuff">
            <input type="hidden" id="hidb" value="other stuff">
        <td>
        <td id="tdJane">
            <input type="hidden" id="hid1" value="some text">
            <input type="hidden" id="hid2" value="other text">
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Into cell `#tdJane`, I wish to insert a new hidden input field below `#hid2`

I tried this:

```
$('#tdJane').html('<input type="hidden" id="hid3" value="newest text">')
```

but that overwrites the existing contents of the cell.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**, `.html()` will overwrite the contents.

```
$('#tdJane').append('<input type="hidden" id="hid3" value="newest text">');
```

You can use jquery element constructor for more clarity.

```
 $('#tdJane').append($('<input/>',{type:'hidden',
                                   id: 'hid3',
                                   value:'newest text'}));
```

See viewsource in this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reSsY/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has a problem, but you should also use jQuery's `.append()` method. Your HTML should look more like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='tdBob'>
      <input type='hidden' id='hida' value='some stuff' />
      <input type='hidden' id='hidb' value'other stuff' />
    </td>
    <td id='tdJane'>
      <input type='hidden' id='hid1' value='some text' />
      <input type='hidden' id='hid2' value='other text' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your jQuery should look more like:

```
$('tdJane').append("<input type='text' id='hid3' value='newest text' />");
```