# Add elements without removing existing content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery `.html()` but is it possible to add an element without to removing the other HTML elements?

My code look so:

```
<div id="contentboxes">
    <div class="con1">content 1</div>
    <div class="con1">content 2</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this with jquery:

```
$('#contentboxes').html('<div class="con3">Content 3</div>');
```

But this command removes my other 2 boxes, is it possible to add without to removing other boxes?

Comment: append(), prepend(), insertBefore(), insertAfter(), before(), after() .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery insert new element into table cell without erasing other elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536561/jquery-insert-new-element-into-table-cell-without-erasing-other-elements)

Comment: I recommend to always have a look at the documentation first: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Also .prepend(), .after() and .before() can be useful

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#contentboxes').append('<div class="con3">Content 3</div>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/